# Remotely connect to an aws-windows instance based MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rdp

1. I have launched an **`AWS`** EC2 **Windows_Server-2016** instance.
2. Since this server is **windows based**,I can successfully connect to
   it using remote desktop connection by entering the username,
   password and a .ppk file.
3. I have installed MySQL server on the instance and created a user
   that is allowed to login with any ip i.e by providing the '%' sign.
4. Here's what my `AWS` instance security group looks like :
   [image]
5. I have tried connecting to the MySQL server using SQLYOG using 2
   different scenarios :

   1. Tried connecting by using the aws public ipv4 address as a host field and
      using mysql username & password
   2. Tried connecting by creating an SSH connection i.e providing server
      username/password and .ppk file in SSH connection panel & then
      providing mysql host/username and localhost in mysql connection
      panel

   None of the methods used allows me to connect.I try same procedure with a linux based server and can connect successfully. Please let me know where am I going wrong while using a **windows based MySQL hosting.**

Comment: what is the error you are seeing?

Comment: @Moe "Can't connect to the MYSQL server on 'ec2-*****************.compute.amazonaws.com' (0)"

Comment: Does the ssh connection go through? Many Windows instances don't have ssh servers installed. Does your Windows firewall on your VM, and or the AWS EC2 firewall, allow inbound TCP connections on port 3306 (MySQL's port)? Do your connection attempts time out after several seconds, or fail immediately? (Usually a timeout means the firewall is set to ignore your incomping request.)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has an extra level of IP protection for remote clients. You have to `GRANT` access to the `remote ip`(your house of office) to be able to connect. As root, you have to do :

```
GRANT ALL ON <db>.* TO '<username>'@'<remote ip>' IDENTIFIED BY '<remote_password>';
```

Where  is the DB you are trying to connect to etc.